# Something usually comes after me. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> How I am, something usually comes after
>
> Without my first and my last, I sound like I'm only one
>
> Remove my third letter and a ball or an animal I might catch
>
> Now read me backwards, I'll be a number

What word am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> **NEXT**

> How I am, something usually comes after

> Something comes **NEXT**

> Without my first and my last, I sound like I'm only one

> <s>N</s>**EX**<s>T</s> → **EX** - no longer a couple, leaving you only single

> Remove my third letter and a ball or an animal I might catch

> **NE**<s>X</s>**T** → **NET** - can catch an animal or ball in one

> Now read me backwards, I'll be a number

> **NET** → **TEN** - a number